# OpenGL Texture is using Linear filtering even though i specified Nearest

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I want to make an 8bit style game, therefore all of my textures are 16x16 going to be scaled up to 128x128. However I noticed that when i did this they were blurry. I anticipated this and used:

`glTexParameteri( GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL11.GL_NEAREST)`

That did not help though. So i set off to research and I found a question that talked about using a black and white checkerboard to find out what is going on. I replaced my texture with a black and white checkerboard and this is what i got:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS9ux.jpg

Strange it seems like even though i am specifying Nearest it is using Linear. Any help?

Edit: My texture is POT, as well is the surface i'm drawing it to.

---

## Texture Drawing Code

```
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    tex.bind();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glTexCoord2d(0,0);
                GL11.glVertex2d(0, 0); // Upper-left
                GL11.glTexCoord2d(1,0);
                GL11.glVertex2d(1024,0); // Upper-right
                GL11.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
                GL11.glVertex2d(1024,1024); // Bottom-right
                GL11.glTexCoord2d(0,1);
                GL11.glVertex2d(0,1024); // Bottom-left
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
```

---

## GL Init Code

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glViewport((int)0, (int)0, (int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight);
GL11.glOrtho(0, 1920, 1440, 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glTexParameteri( GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL11.GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glTexParameteri( GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL11.GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Can you post some code - in specific the part where you are rendering, as well as and setup for GL? It would help in case there is an issue with the code.

Comment: Sure give me a few minutes.

Comment: I solved the problem. I was using a library called slick, this library was changing my desired filter within its Texture class. so i had to use Texture.setTextureFilter

Comment: Ah excellent, figured it would be something to that extent.